# UICollectionViewController flow layout with readable content width

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` using flow layout, and I'm trying to achieve the same margins as a `UITableViewController` with readable content width.

The closest I've come to matching this layout behavior is to embed a `UICollectionViewController` within a `UIViewController` and have the embedded view "Follow Readable Width".

[image: UICollectionViewController embedded in UIViewController]

Here the teal color is the `UIViewController` and the salmon color is the `UICollectionViewController`.  The problem is the teal area doesn't scroll the `UICollectionView` and the scroll indicators are also not along the edge of the screen like you would expect.

My question is:

> How can I achieve this layout without having to embed a `UICollectionViewController`?

My guess is that I can somehow set the `UICollectionView` left and right section insets to match the readable content guide margins and update them by overriding `viewWillTransition(to size: with coordinator:)` and observing `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange` notifications, but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: The image you've shown doesn't have enough content to scroll, so it's not clear (to me, anyway) what the issue is. Maybe also post an image of how you *want* it to look?

Comment: He wants the red collection view to look exactly the same as above but without using the teal view controller as a container - for example by using section insets instead to narrow the width to match the readable content guide.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem with Swift 5.1 and iOS 13, you can set your flow layout's [`sectionInsetReference`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/sectioninsetreference) property to [`.fromContentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/sectioninsetreference/fromcontentinset),  set your collection view's [`insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891101-insetslayoutmarginsfromsafearea) property to `false` and set your collection view's [`contentInset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset)s to match the `view`'s `readableContentGuide`'s insets.

---

The following sample code shows a possible implementation in order to have a collection view that has a readable content width:

*ViewController.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(
        frame: .zero,
        collectionViewLayout: ColumnFlowLayout(cellsPerRow: 5)
    )
    var collectionViewNeedsLayout = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Demo"

        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if collectionViewNeedsLayout {
            let margin = view.readableContentGuide.layoutFrame.origin.x
            collectionView.contentInset.left = margin
            collectionView.contentInset.right = margin
            collectionViewNeedsLayout = false
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        collectionViewNeedsLayout = true
    }

}
```

```swift
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 59
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        return cell
    }

}
```

*ColumnFlowLayout.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class ColumnFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    let cellsPerRow: Int

    init(cellsPerRow: Int) {
        self.cellsPerRow = cellsPerRow

        super.init()

        self.sectionInsetReference = .fromContentInset
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        let marginsAndInsets = collectionView.contentInset.left + collectionView.contentInset.right + sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right + minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellsPerRow - 1)
        let itemWidth = ((collectionView.bounds.width - marginsAndInsets) / CGFloat(cellsPerRow)).rounded(.down)
        itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemWidth)
    }

}
```

*Cell.swift*

```swift
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("not implemnted")
    }

}
```

---

Display on iPhone 11 Pro Max:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 14+ with a diffable data source, you can use `section.contentInsetsReference = .readableContent`.

This will adjusts the section insets and follows the readable guide.

Answer (score 0):

You hunch is correct, the simplest way to do this is via the collection view's `insetForSection`. In my experience, the following is required:

- Return the collection view's `directionalLayoutMargins` as the inset (use `.leading` and .`trailing`
- Disable automatic safe area handling via `collectionView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = false`
- Manually set the collection view's `directionalLayoutMargins` using `view.readableContentGuide.layoutFrame.origin.x`. Note that I am using *view*.readableContentGuide, not that of the `collectionView`.
- Update the `directionalLayoutMargins` in exactly the same way whenever `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange`

Still would be good to know how to accomplish this without any type of container